# Assert and unused local variable warning in GCC don't mix well?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a problem with the unused local variable warning in GCC.

Often I have code that looks like this:

```
bool success = foo();
assert(success);
```

This is fine for debug builds. In release however, the assert compiles to nothing, and GCC gives me a warning.

What is the best way to work around this? Wrapping the `bool success =` with #ifdef just does not seem like a nice solution...

Comment: Does foo() return a value purely for debugging?

Comment: AFAIK assertions are ignored only when a special macro/variable (like `NDEBUG`) is defined. If not defined, assertions should work in both modes.

Comment: Mh, doesn't sound like a very good idea to me to have function which returns a `bool` to indicated success or failure only check in debug builds and just assume it succeeded in release mode.

Comment: `assert(!success)` means you want to assert that there's a failure...

Comment: No, foo() is production code - isn't that obvious from the name?

Comment: ChrisWue: I get what you are saying, but somehow there always are the situations where proper error handling means doing nothing. For example, you get a packet to push to a fixed-size queue, but the queue is full - what do you do? Simple answer, just let the push fail.

Comment: @kotlinski: or abort the app.

Comment: But isn't that an abuse of the assert? As a maintenance programmer I would find this non-self documenting and confusing. Asserts to me are meant to check that code is being properly invoked, not that a subsystem is failing in debug builds only. This is also a violation of test what you fly, fly what you test. Why return a bool if you're just going to ignore it in the releae code? At the very least the assert would be better off in the called method at the point of failure. In your example, I often push an error entry into the last available queue slot, if I don't have a logging mechanism.

Comment: Tod: Yes, I think you are rather spot on here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would probably define a macro specific to this scenario

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define verify(expression) assert(expression)
#else
#define verify(expression) expression
#endif
```

I prefer this approach over using a local variable because it doesn't pollute the method with values that only conditionally exist.

In general I find it very helpful to have 2 sets of macros in my projects

- assertXXX: debug only execution
- verifyXXX: retail + debug execution

Comment: This is nice, but has the downside that if `expression` contains function calls, they may not be optimised away.

Comment: @Oli, how so?  I don't see how it could be optimized away since in DEBUG it will go through assert which forces the call and in non-debug the function call just stands on it's own which can't be optimized away.

Comment: @Jared: That's my point.  What if you don't need to be calling the functions other than to compute a value that's going to be asserted?  Also, in GCC with `-Wall` at least, a standalone expression (as you'd get in non-debug mode) raises a warning/error, which takes us back to where we started!

Comment: @Oli in that case you should use assert directly.  The diff between assert and verify is 1) debug only assertion 2) debug and non-debug assertion.

Comment: @Michael gotcha. In my code bases i tend to have assert = debug, verify = debug + non-debug. So if the intent is assert only then I would use assert over verify.

Comment: @Oli would the `-Wall` case be due to the unconsumed return value? If so is casting to void an option with GCC? I know it is with MS C++ but it's been too long since i did serious GCC development

Comment: @Jared: This is the problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @Oli The issue the OP is struggling with is GCC complaining about an unused local, not an unused function return value.  It's not 100% clear about it but they mention not liking a `#if DEBUG bool success ...` solution

Comment: @Jared: Yes, you're right.  It's the unused variable that's the problem.

Comment: @Oli: if the OP wanted `foo` not to be called in release mode, he probably would have used `assert(foo())` to begin with. The other warning you mention can be avoided via an unused attribute in the verify macro.

Comment: Or `#ifndef NDEBUG`, since that's what's defined to control `assert`.

Comment: @Jared: N in NDEBUG stands for NOT, so now it's backwards. `#ifndef NDEBUG` is a double-negative but it's idiomatic, and the way to go. Also, might as well add `#endif`.

Comment: @JaredPar: and counter-intuitively `#define NDEBUG 0` *disables* asserts, same as `#define NDEBUG 1`. So to follow the idiom used in the standard it does have to be `#ifdef`, not just `#if`: `#ifdef NDEBUG #define verify(e) e #else #define verify(e) assert(e)` . Of course it's up to the application writer exactly what they define `NDEBUG` to be, so if you really don't want to do that it's probably reasonable to document that anyone defining it to anything so daft/perverse as `0` will not get sensible behavior out of your `verify` macro...

Comment: @Oli: I think the best solution is to use both macros in conjunction. OP already moved the function call out of `assert` because he always wants it. Calling the new macro `assert_eval` for example allows either `assert_eval( foo() );` or `bool success = foo(); assert_eval( success );` with no warnings.

Answer (score 8):

I use a macro

```
#define UNUSED(x) ((void)(x))
```

used like so:

```
UNUSED(success);
```

macro to silence the warning and to document that the fact that the variable is unused (at least at in some builds) is intentional/ok.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know about GCC, but this has always worked in Microsoft Visual C++:

```
(void) success;
```

It references the variable without actually doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [variable attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes) to mark it as potentially unused.

Comment: Excellent! 8-) I have that problem in one of my libraries with a static variable definition in a header that's not always being used. Although this doesn't answer this question very well because the programmer wanted a solution that works with g++ and cl...

Comment: Nevermind, actually this question is GCC specific! 8-) I'm mixing up with another I read just before I guess. So totally perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `NDEBUG` macro, which is defined when assert are not used, for example:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
  bool success =
#endif
    foo();
  assert(success);
```

**EDIT:** This will effectively "kill" the warning, as the `#ifndef` will ensure that there simply is no variable to warn about.

Comment: The problem is not that it doesn't get optimized away, the problem is that GCC throws a warning.

Comment: This will effectively "kill" the warning, as the `#ifndef` will ensure that there simply is no variable to warn about.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly more concise form Lindydancer's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626499/188610) at the cost of defining a helper macro.  Here is the helper macro:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define DEBUG_ONLY( ... ) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#  define DEBUG_ONLY( ... )
#endif
```

Then it can be used like so:

```
DEBUG_ONLY( bool success = ) foo();
assert( success );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GCC-specific `unused` attribute. It is usually defined to a short form that is easy to remove from the code for non-GCC compilers.